# Creating a version of a generic function with the type 'clamped'

Tags: generics, typescript

Let's say I have a function that returns some type parameterized by a generic. I'm going to be using this function a lot. Most of the time I'll be using one particular type - say `number`. For convenience, it would be nice to have an alias of this function just for numbers.

Toy example:

```
function arrayMaker<T>() : Array<T> {
    return new Array<T>();
}
let numericalArrayMaker: () => Array<number> = arrayMaker<number>;
```

But the TypeScript compiler complains about the last line, thinking that I'm assigning type `number[]` to numericalArrayMaker.

I'm confused about why this fails, because I can assign a function (without a generic type) to a variable:

```
function foo() { return 0; }
let foo2 = foo;
```

... and I can assign a type (with a generic) to a variable:

```
type numericalArray = myArray<number>;
```

Is there a different syntax for what I'm trying to do?

(I understand that I could make my example work using a factory function returning "arrayMakers", but that becomes a good deal more verbose, and leads to some code duplication if my function takes arguments.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is save a reference of arrayMaker to another variable with the type you want:

```
function arrayMaker<T>() : Array<T> {
    return new Array<T>();
}

let numericalArrayMaker: () => Array<number> = arrayMaker
let mynums: number[] = numericalArrayMaker();
```

You can not use the generics with the function signature if you're not calling it, like: `arrayMaker<number>`, it makes no real sense.

---

#### Edit

I'm not sure why the compiler doesn't complain about

```
let numericalArrayMaker: (string) => number[] = arrayMaker;
```

It might be a bug, or maybe there's a better explanation which eludes me, if you do open an issue please post the url as a comment as I'd like to flow on that.

You can go around this issue though like this:

```
type ArrayMaker<T> = (value: T) => T[];

let numericalArrayMaker: ArrayMaker<number> = arrayMaker;
let mynums: number[] = numericalArrayMaker("foo"); // error
```

As for why this:

```
let a = arrayMaker<number>;
```

doesn't make sense, is that you are assigning a reference to the `arrayMaker` function into variable `a`, but there's no such thing as generics in js so there's no meaning to `arrayMaker<number>`.
What you want is casting:

```
let a = arrayMaker as arrayMaker<number>;
```

Maybe it will be clearer with classes:

```
class A<T> {}

let a1 = A<number>; // error
let a2 = A as A<number>; / ok
```

This works with:

```
type numericalArray = myArray<number>;
```

Because here you're dealing with the type of `myArray` and not the actual function.

This brings up something else that I personally believe in:
Don't write code in typescript for typescript, that is if the compiled code you wrote doesn't do anything, it was just written to get your ts compiling, then it's probably a bad idea.

I think that it's best to just go with:

```
let mynums: number[] = arrayMaker(4);
```

Comment: It seems like this leads to some loss of type safety though. For example [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20arrayMaker%3CT%3E(member%3A%20T)%20%3A%20Array%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5Bmember%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20numericalArrayMaker%3A%20(string)%20%3D%3E%20Array%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20arrayMaker%3B%0D%0Alet%20mynums%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%3D%20numericalArrayMaker(%22foo%22)%3B) compiles without issue, but it seems like it shouldn't.

Comment: Also, could you elaborate on why such a construction makes no sense? Does it lead to some ambiguity? Its meaning seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I was able to find a number of existing issues related to this - e.g. [8459](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8459), [3410](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3410). The short answer is that Typescript's "assignability relation ignores generics and constraints in signatures. It just replaces all type parameters with `any`." (Apparently because to do otherwise would be slow.)